# How to ignore contents from table of contents in standard report class?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table of contents starting on page 3.

I use  `\tableofcontents` to generate it.

My actual generated pdfs contents page looks like this

```
contents..............3
chapter1...........6
chapter2.............19
```

How to ignore this `contents.........3` line?

I am not using the class `memoir`, I m using `report` so the duplicate doesnt work for me.

**Answer :** 
As pointed out by @egreg.

Use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` instead of `\usepackage{tocbibind}`

Comment: The standard classes use the starred form of the sectioning command for the table of contents. This form does not add an entry in the table of contents. A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) shows the class, packages and options that might be responsible for the observed behavior.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek As far as I know, only `memoir` has the star form of `\tableofcontents`. With the standard classes the problem might be caused by having `\usepackage{tocbibind}` instead of `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Comment: thanks @egreg \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} solved the problem